# Is it correct to use present perfect continuous in Conditional sentences Type 2?

Tags: grammaticality

It is taught widely as standard:

*Conditional type* 2: If I **wasn't helping** you now, you **would fail** tomorrow.
*Conditional type 3*: If I **hadn't been helping** you yesterday, you **would have failed**.

*My question*: I **haven't been helping** you all this time, up to now, so you will fail.

How do I say it in a *Conditional sense type 2*?

If I **have been helping** you all this time? (We cannot use any Present Tense, acc. to the rule).

If I **was helping** you all this time? (Then we lose Perfect Continuous aspect)

If I **had been helping** you? (But we cannot use Past Perfect Continuous, used in the Type 3, if we mean it in relation to a present moment).

So what is the answer, PLEASE...

Comment: I don't believe we should accept questions that mention numbered conditionals, unless the questioner explains precisely what they are. My suspicion is that there are N numbered conditionals, where N is a large integer, and the numbers are assigned by ESL teachers, each using their own numbers.

Comment: Thanks for you input. However: a) If someone wasn't familiar with "Conditional Types", I have given clear examples with clear and different meanings. and b) You have not answered my question, just your "suspicious unhelpful opinion".

Comment: Well, you see, the question as posed has some problems. I don't know what you want as an answer. I don't know why you "can't use past perfect continuous"; what happens when you do? Perhaps someone else can do it. But you might want to think about why you're asking it.